# Using a function define var and then passing to a constructor

Tags: python, function, oop, object, nameerror

I want client code to call a function, that assigns user inputted values to variables and pass them to an object to be used as user defined attributes.

But I'm not able to call any methods for the object

I've tried including the methods for the object in the function, but it doesn't seem to change anything, same error.

```
def function():

    a = input("blahblah")
    the_object = foo(a)

class foo(object):
    def __init__(a):
        self.a = a   #This works fine
        print(self.a) 

    def DoThing():   #This does not
        print(self.a)

#Main
function()
the_object.DoThing()
```

I can see that the function is called, and the object is created.
But when I try to call any methods, I keep getting the error

NameError: name 'the_object' is not defined

Comment: the_object only exist in your function() function. return the_object in your function() function, and you can assign it a variable name when you call function()

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Answer (score 0):

```
def function():
    a = input("blahblah")
    return foo(a)

class foo(object):
    def __init__(object):
        self.a = object
        print(self.a) 

    def DoThing():
        print(self.a)

#Main
the_object = function()
the_object.DoThing()
```

or

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(object):
        self.a = object
        print(self.a) 

    def DoThing():
        print(self.a)

the_object = foo("blahblah")
the_object.DoThing()
```